# Is it kufr to imagine Allah as a mighty image, e.g. for worship?

Tags: quran, hadith, fiqh, kufr

I know that nothing is similar to Allah (Surah Al - Ikhlas). But human nature wants to visualize what it is worshiping.

In Salah ihsan means worshiping Allah as if you are seeing him because even though you don't see him, he sees you. If someone during worship were to imagine Allah in the shape of a mighty and beautiful being that has a very strong and beautiful light and is astonishingly big and mighty and beautiful.

My question is: **Would he commit major kufr even though he had only the good intention of giving a mighty image in his imagination to the being he is worshiping?**

There is also a famous hadith about Isra and Mi'raj where they ask the prophet s.a.w. Did you see Allah. He s.a.w replies: What could I see. There was only light.

Comment: Edit my question if it is necessary but please don't delete it because it is very important to me.

Comment: Wa alaikumu As-Salamu wa rahmatu-llahi wa barakatuh. Brother of course it is very important to ask questions and get an answer, since asking questions is the cure for ignorance, may Allah increase us in knowledge. But I recommend you to ask a scholar since many questions on this site go unanswered, or are answered badly. If you can't ask a scholar (or you're too shy), you may ask on sites such as IslamQA.info - HadithAnswers.com - SeekersGuidance.org - DarulFiqh.com / but be patient and stay steadfast my brother. May Allah guide us

Comment: I made some edits; here's my recommendation for how to proceed: I feel the first question is unproblematic and answerable, but having two-questions-in-one makes it harder to answer [it's just how the site is designed].  So I suggest only asking the first question here, and after understanding its answers, ask the second question separately.  (In fact, since there's no answers yet, I'll make those edits too...)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. With concentration in salah. Sometime people have many things in their mind. And that is very disturbing in salah.

Yes, You will commit major sin if you try to visualize Allah. Because "No one is comparable to Him." (Surah AL-Ikhlas) As you also mention it. And It is also true that human nature wants to visualize if he's trying to concentrate on something. But It is haram to do so.

So solution to your problem is, According to most Islamic scholars, You have to concentrate  to the meaning of what we recite. Not only you can concentrate in salah. But You can also find true peace in your mind, the true happiness from salah.
So start by knowing what is meaning of surahs. Like start memorizing the meaning of surah fatiha here https://quran.com/1 . And slowly slowly try to know every meaning of what you recite in salah. And in that way we can get more closer to Allah.

Answer (score 0):

It is not kufr if you do it accidentally. Most likely it is the whispers of Shaitan.

Abu Hurairah (RA) narrated:

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Allah has forgiven my followers the evil thoughts that occur to their minds, as long as such thoughts are not put into action or uttered." ([Sahih Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/68/19))

If you seek forgiveness from it, it should be enough.

However, doing so willfully would be sinful because it is going against what Allah clearly said in the Quran:

> There is nothing similar to Him, and He is the Hearing, the Seeing. ([Quran 41:11](https://quran.com/42/11))

And just like it is forbidden to build idols or worship them, it is forbidden to build an image of Allah in your mind. Allah has no image and we must worship Him unseen or unknown.

In the first few verses it is mentioned about the guided people:

> Those who believe in the unseen, establish prayer, and spend out of what We have provided for them, (Quran 2:3)

Note the word "unseen" (Al-Ghaib). We are supposed to believe in Allah in a manner where we do not see Him, know how He looks, or try to imagine a way He looks.